# Cannot read property 'touched' of undefined in angular6 reactive forms

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

i have written code to validate page,but am getting error like ' Cannot read property 'touched' of undefined'.please any one help me this code.please any one correct if am wrong.

html:

```
<div class="container pt-4">
    <form [formGroup]="goalForm" (submit)="submit()">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">Sub Goals</div>
            <div class="card-body" formArrayName="subgoals">
                <div *ngFor="let goal of goalForm.controls.subgoals.controls; let i=index">
                    <div [formGroupName]="i" class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                            <label for="name">Criteria Name *</label>
                            <input class="form-control" formControlName="criteria_name" type="text" 
                                    id="criteria_name" name="criteria_name" 
                                    placeholder="Criteria Name">
                            <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="goalForm.controls['criteria_name'].touched 
                                    && goalForm.controls['criteria_name'].hasError('required')">
                                    Criteria Name is required! </span>
                        </div>                            
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                            <label for="weightage">Criteria Weightage *</label>
                            <input class="form-control" formControlName="criteria_weightage" type="number" 
                                    id="criteria_weightage" name="criteria_weightage" 
                                    placeholder="Criteria Weightage">
                            <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="goalForm.controls['criteria_weightage'].touched 
                                    && goalForm.controls['criteria_weightage'].hasError('required')">
                                    Criteria Weightage is required! </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>     
    </form>
</div>
```

kpa-goal.component.ts:

```
 ngOnInit(){
        this.goalForm = this.fb.group({
            subgoals :this.fb.array([
              this.initgoal(),
            ])
          });
    }
    initgoal(){
        return this.fb.group({
          criteria_name: [null,Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
          criteria_weightage: [null,Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
          });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually had a *FormArray* (subgoals) inside your *FormGroup* and the 2 fields (criteria_name & criteria_weightage) were inside the FormArray... so you had to access the 2 fields by traversing the subgoals before you could get to your 2 fields (criteria_name & criteria_weightage).

relevant **HTML**:

```
<div class="container pt-4">
        <form [formGroup]="goalForm" (submit)="submit()">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Sub Goals</div>
                <div class="card-body" formArrayName="subgoals">
                    <div *ngFor="let goal of goalForm.controls.subgoals.controls; let i=index">
                        <div [formGroupName]="i" class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                                <label for="name">Criteria Name *</label>
                  <input class="form-control" formControlName="criteria_name" type="text" 
                          id="criteria_name" name="criteria_name" 
                          placeholder="Criteria Name">
                          <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="goalForm.controls.subgoals.controls[0].controls.criteria_name.touched && goalForm.controls.subgoals.controls[0].controls.criteria_name.errors?.required" >
                          Criteria Name is required! 
                          </span>
              </div>                            
              <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                  <label for="weightage">Criteria Weightage *</label>
                  <input class="form-control" formControlName="criteria_weightage" type="number" 
                          id="criteria_weightage" name="criteria_weightage" 
                          placeholder="Criteria Weightage">
                          <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="goalForm.controls.subgoals.controls[0].controls.criteria_weightage.touched && goalForm.controls.subgoals.controls[0].controls.criteria_weightage.errors?.required" >
                          Criteria Weightage is required!
                          </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>     
    </form>
</div>
```

complete working [demo on stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-svsybi)